# Calling Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog.ShowAsync throws exception

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-8, .net-4.5

I'm trying to use Windows 8 desktop application message dialog,

 running the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using Windows.UI.Popups;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Hope it will work", "TRY");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**But I get the following exception:**

"Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)"

Can anyone explain why? and how can I solve this issue?

Note: 
I added the following properties to csproj file:

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
```

And a reference to "Windows.winmd" to the project references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208674

at the bottom you will see :

**Minimum supported client** Windows 8 [Windows Store apps only]

If you are not developing a Windows Store App (Windows 8 **specific** app), but a WPF application, use the `MessageBox` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602949.aspx)

I see you have ran into a confusion. 'Windows 8' there is used as 'Windows Store Apps' ('Windows 8 Apps', 'WinRT Apps').

Comment: Thanks. DialogMessage is unlike [ToastNotification class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.aspx) that can be used on Desktop Apps.